# How to map TridionPageProvider.PublicationId to web.config[appSettings.PublicationId]

Tags: configuration, dd4t

For multi-publicational purpose I need all publications to override some items in appSettings area of the web.config file of my web application.

**Is there a clever way that my TridionPageProvider.PublicationId property to be binded to appSettings/MyPublication.PublicationId?**

**I do not want to override this part of the web.config in the sub-config files.**

Now, by default the web.config looks like:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
      ...
      <add key="MyPublication.PublicationId" value="6"/>
    </appSettings>
    ...
    <unity>
      <typeAliases>
        ...
        <typeAlias alias="IPageProvider"
                 type="DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.IPageProvider, DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts" />
        ...
        <typeAlias alias="PageProvider"
                 type="DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1.TridionPageProvider, DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1" />
      </typeAliases>
      <containers>
        <container name="main">
          <types>
            <!-- map the implementations to the interfaces -->
            <type type="IPageProvider" mapTo="PageProvider">
            <!--          <lifetime type="singleton" /> -->
              <property name="PublicationId" type="int" value="0"/>
            </type>
            ...
         <types>
        </container>
      <containers>
    </unity>
</configuration>
```

My solution at the moment is:

1. create a new class which inherits TridionPageProvider
2. create a
   new PublicationId property with "new" modifier and hiding the
   parent's property
3. when the setter is called check if the
   value is "-1" and if it is true then check
   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyPublication.PublicationId"] and
   set that value to the parent's property

But I think there is a better solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DD4T now contains a PublicationResolver which helps you deal with multi-publication web sites.

Basically, each factory (e.g. the PageFactory) now has a PublicationResolver attached, whose job it is to return the publication id for the current request. 
It is explained (including code examples) in this post: http://blog.trivident.com/2013/01/dd4t-web-publication-resolving/.